# The method setProjectId(String) is undefined for the type BigQueryOptions.Builder

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a BigQuery REST API call, but getting an error:

The method setProjectId(String) is undefined for the type BigQueryOptions.Builder

When trying to run this line of code within the Main:

```
BigQuery BigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(“123456789“).build().getService();
```

I have the following dependencies in my pom file:

- google-cloud-bigquery version 2.24.4
- google-cloud-core version 2.15.0

I have tried other artifacts too, but doesn’t seem to be working…

I am trying to get the results from the data table.

————————————————————————————

If I move my code from Eclipse to IntelliJ, I then get a different error message for the same line of code:

class file for com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions not found